# Turbopack Monorepo: next/font/google giving error

Tags: next.js, monorepo, turborepo

I started off with next turborepo example project.

First I ran the command:

```
npx create-turbo@latest -e with-tailwind
```

It created 2 apps, web and doc. Web app is itself a complete next app. In it, I went to the _app.tsx and added the recommended way to add a google font.

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
```

But it gives me error:

```
Server Error
Error: You tried to import `next/font/google`, did you mean `@next/font/google`?
```

This fonts setup works on normal next setups but not working with turborepo monorepo. I attempted to add @next/font package manually to the web workspace and updating the import but it also didn't work.

Next JS version in package json is latest. I checked by command, it is Next.js v13.0.4

Can someone explain why it is not working and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer why, but I had the same issue in our Turborepo.

Right now we have dependencies of:

```
"next": "13.1.1",
"@next/font": "13.1.0",
```

And it's working, but I also need to find out why before we go into production.